Trigger pipeline only when Pull Request Merge complete
I have an Azure Pipeline that needs to be triggered only when the Pull Request is completed.
The Pipeline is using Azure Repo.
Now, I have the following trigger settings in Azure Pipeline.
trigger:
 branches:
  include:
    - main

When the Pull Request is completed, it indeed can trigger the Pipeline. But if I do any commits on the main branch, it will trigger the Pipeline too.
Are there any methods can trigger the Pipeline only when the Pull Request is completed?
I have tried to check the variables: Build.reason , System.PullRequest. But they cannot work in the pipeline trigger.

if I do any commits on the main branch, it will trigger the Pipeline too - you shouldn't commit changes directly to the main branch - ideally, everything should go through a pull request. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

I am afraid that Azure DevOps pipeline has no out-of-box method can trigger the pipeline only when the Pull Request is completed.

Are there any methods can trigger the Pipeline only when the Pull Request is completed?

I suggest that you can use the Webhook and Resource Webhook trigger in Azure Pipeline.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Create a webhook in Project Settings -> Service hooks -> Webhook.
For example:

You can set the event: Pull Request Update and set the Change: Status Changed.
Then you can set the Webhook URL:
https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview"

In this case, when the Pull Request state change, it will trigger the Webhook.
Step2: Create an Incoming Webhook in Project Settings-> Service Connections. Refer to this doc: Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines
Step3: You can disable the CI trigger(trigger: none) and setup the Webhook trigger in Pipeline and the trigger filter:
trigger: none
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: webhookname          ### Webhook alias
      connection: serviceconnectionname    ### Incoming webhook service connection
      filters:
        - path: resource.status    ### JSON path in the payload
          value: completed     ### Expected value in the path provided

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.testkevin.resource.status}}

In this case, when the Pull Request status change, it will trigger the webhook and send the request to trigger pipeline.
It will contains the Pull Request Status.

If the status is completed, the Webhook trigger will trigger the Pipeline.
If you directly do commits in main branch, it will not trigger the pipeline.

I was able to solve it in a really easy way.
Just adding "pr: none" to my pipeline after the trigger.
So when there is a pull request it doesn't trigger before the end of the merge. Just when the merge is completed it triggers the pipeline after the branch receives the new changes.
I followed the microsoft documentacion from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers

trigger:
- <branch_name>

pr: none


Thanks, with this setting, can I still access the pull request ID (number)? as I am building a pipeline to clean up pull request resources
